# MacBook fan does not speed up causing overheating despite sensors and fan are ok

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature

I have an issue with my Macbook pro retina 13 2014 (A1502):

despite high CPU usage, the fan spins constantly at 1300 RPM, which causes the CPU temperature raise up to 80C.

This happened after i heavily broke my macbook and tried to repair it by replacing its aluminium body, its broken screen assembly and its noisy fan (was a bit bended which caused noise).

All temperature sensors seem to work fine and I can manually adjust fan speed as well as it can be changed by MFC.

Also i tried 3 different fans and the situation doesn't change.

I tried to reset SMC, pram and to reinstall the system (was cooling down CPU manually, don't ask how)

Atm i am using MacFanControl to regulate the speed of the fan, but the issue is still present and causing some discomfort, like i can't install new OS because MFC doesn't run during OS installation and i am afraid of overheating.

Despite all components look good, the system doesn't regulate the speed of the fan.

It is interesting that after i disconnected touchpad the fan was speeding up normally when CPU temperature was raising. The downside of this was that macbook was constantly throttling , CPU usage was 300% and everything was very slow. I had the same symptoms when camera's cable was damaged.

Can anybody help me with this please?

Thanks

Comment: according to the spec, its intel cpu will shut down when the temperature hits 105C, but i don't want to try. I think running CPU above 80 and especially above 90 will not make its life longer. I tried to start world of tanks and the temperature skyrockets up to 80, and i shut down without waiting till it hits 90. But the thing is that i clearly saw the difference in fan speed pattern: 1. when i run MBP without MFC and 2. when i pulled out its touchpad. in case 2 the fan was speeding up proportionally to the CPU load and heat.

Comment: Sounds like the touchpad is affecting the sensor.